# Button is Triggered for the First time only, After that Button is not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a Next Button in Parent Component, And When I click on that Next Button, A Dialog box will open and that dialog box has two Option : "Yes" Or "No"(Which is in Child Component).. When I Click on "No" Button it should hide the Dialog box and it is working Fine..... Now Issue is When dialog box is hidden and Again When I click on Next button again and again, That dialog box popup is not showing up... I Think some Issue in the child Comp with the No Button.... Can anyone help me in this...Thanks in advance....

Parent Component :

```js
  constructor {
    this.state = { enableNextButton: false}
    }

   checking () {
    let { add1, countryCode, stateProvince, zip, companyName } = this.state;
    let payload = {
      address_l1: add1,
      country: countryCode,
    };
    this.setState({
      enableNextButton: false,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.checking()}
          className={
            this.state.enableNextButton ? "primary" : "primary disabled"
          }
        >
          <span className="back">Next &gt; </span>
        </button>
        <BarLoader
          width={"50%"}
          color={"#84B135"}
          loading={this.props.addLoader}
        />
      </div>

      <ChildComp />
      />
    </>
  );
```

Child Comp () :

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showDialog: true
      };
  }

  handleNoButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showDialog: false });
  };

  <div

  
        </p>
        <div className="padding-around">
          Do you wish to continue with below address?
        </div>
        <div>
            </button>
            <button
              className="primary"
              onClick={() => this.handleNoButtonClick()}
            >
              NO
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the parent component you are calling the child component anyway and from the child component you want to controle its styling depends on its state.
 when you click the NO button the child component rerendes with the new `className` but `enableNextButton` state in the parent component remains `false` so when you click the next button again, `enableNextButton` will be set to `false`, **and since it is already `false`**, this won't rerender the parent component so the child component won't be rerendered too, therefore `showDialog` is still `false` there.

to avoid this one solution is to manage how to set `enableNextButton` to `true` when the NO button is clicked,
however a better approach is to move `showDialog` to the parent component and decide from there if the child component should be displayed or which className should take

```js
// add showDialog to your state in the parent component
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    enableNextButton: false,
    showDialog: false
  };
}

checking() {
  let { add1, countryCode } = this.state;
  let payload = {
    address_l1: add1,
    country: countryCode
  };

  this.setState({
    enableNextButton: false,
    // set it to true when next button is clicked
    showDialog: true
  });
}

setShowDialogTofalse() {
 this.setState({ showDialog: false });
}

//...
<DisclaimerDomainDialog
  //...
  setShowDialogTofalse={this.setShowDialogTofalse.bind(this)}
  showDialog={this.state.showDialog}
/>
```

now you get rif of `showDialog` state in the child component so you use `this.props.showDialog` instead of `this.state.showDialog` so when you click the NO button you want to set `showDialog` of the parent component to `false`:

```js
<button onClick={() => {
  this.props.setShowDialogTofalse();
}}>
 NO
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am Bit Confused here, Can You Please Modify my Code with Necessary changes to work

Comment: I think No Button is in Child Comp, So I need to receive that in Constructor right? CAn You please Check once and Update

Comment: SO No need to do any changes in Child Comp?? Only to add that ShowDailog in the Parent comp?

Comment: @Sundeep one last update, this should work

Answer (score 0):

Once, you click the button, handleNoButtonClick() method updates the showDialog state to false.

```
<div
className={
  this.props.openDialog && this.state.showDialog(it is false)
    ? "dialog-open"
    : "dialog-close"
}
```

> 

So, Dialog is not showing up. After, parents component doesn't have method that update showDialog to true.

Comment: Yes You are Correct...How Can I send that to parent Component and update there, Can You Please Modify my Code with Necessary changes to work